# Using Spatial Join with Count in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, count, error-000714

Using ArcMap 10.2 I am getting the ERROR: 000714 for this script. Therefore I am having trouble debugging it.

The purpose of my script is to spatially join points to lines in ArcGIS. And is simply a test script that will become part of a larger scripted tool. The script I am currently working off is as per below which is largely a copy/paste from [ArcGIS Spatial Join Help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm), which I have modified for my .shp files and a count field.

```
# Spatial Join Script
# Initiating top of catchment junction connections to pipes.
# Process: Spatially join points to lines with count field.

# Import system modules
import os
import arcpy

# Set workspace environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/.../Python/SpatialJoinTest"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


# Script arguments

PointInput = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)
LineInput = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)

#Set Variables
Outputs = "C:/.../Python/SpatialJoinTest/Outputs"
LW = Outputs + "/" + "LineWorking.shp"
PW = Outputs + "/" + "JunctionWorking.shp"

O_PL = Outputs + "/" + "PointLine_JoinCount.shp"

# Creating Working Shapefiles
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (LineInput, LW)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (PointInput, PW)

# Want to join Points to Lines and 'count' the number of joins for each pipe to junction
''' I note that in this section in the help file .gdb were referenced rather than .shp
    Thus: I think it is these lines where I am going wrong(?)'''
targetFeatures = os.path.join(PW)
joinFeatures = os.path.join(LW)

# Output will be the target features, (Points) with the 'count' of Lines joined.
outfc = os.path.join(O_PL)

# Create a new fieldmappings and add the two input feature classes.
fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldmappings.addTable(targetFeatures)
fieldmappings.addTable(joinFeatures)

# First get the 'L_ID' fieldmap. 'L_ID' is a field in the 'LW' feature class.
# The output will have the 'ID' with the 'count' of connecting lines. Setting the
# field's merge rule to 'count' will count the connections for all of the points for
# each line intersecting. The field is also renamed to be more appropriate
# for the output.
L_IDFieldIndex = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("L_ID")
fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(L_IDFieldIndex)

# Get the output field's properties as a field object
field = fieldmap.outputField

# Rename the field and pass the updated field object back into the field map
field.name = "L_COUNT"
field.aliasName = "L_COUNT"
fieldmap.outputField = field

# Set the merge rule to mean and then replace the old fieldmap in the mappings object
# with the updated one
fieldmap.mergeRule = "Count"
fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(L_IDFieldIndex, fieldmap)

#Run the Spatial Join tool, using the defaults for the join operation and join type
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(targetFeatures, joinFeatures, outfc, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_COMMON", fieldmappings, "INTERSECT")
```

How can I make the above work?

My guess is it is to do with os.path.join() commands, however my experience is limited.

The error message is below:

> Running script SpatialJoinScript... ERROR 000714: Error in script
>   SpatialJoinScript. Error in executing: cmd.exe /C
>   D:...\Python\SpatialJoinScript.py  "D:\Michael Austin -
>   Working\GIS\Python\20180323\Inputs\Point.shp"
>   "D:...\Python\20180323\Inputs\Line.shp"
>
> Failed to execute (SpatialJoinScript). Failed at Mon Apr 09 11:57:52
>   2018 (Elapsed Time: 0.06 seconds)

Comment: Can you write the error message in your post?

Comment: It could be the hyphen in your source path, try changing "D:\Michael Austin - Working" to "D:\Michael Austin Working"

Comment: That's a particularly non-helpful error message, can you put in a couple of arcpy.AddMessage(sys._getframe().f_lineno) statements (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056048/filename-and-line-number-of-python-script) to find out what line the error is on - you will need to import sys first.

Comment: Yes, your os.path.join() commands don't look correct.  Try `targetFeatures = os.path.join(Outputs, "JunctionWorking.shp")`

Comment: No, that's fine @Dan, Outputs = "C:/.../Python/SpatialJoinTest/Outputs" so os.path.join(Outputs, "JunctionWorking.shp") returns "C:/.../Python/SpatialJoinTest/Outputs\\JunctionWorking.shp" - assuming of course that the ... in C:/.../ is an obfuscation of a path and isn't copied verbatim.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, just looks ugly to me and then the os.path.join with a single path is doing nothing.

Comment: I just did a test with a hyphen in the path name and it worked fine...I think @MichaelStimson may have it with the "C:/.../" path, can you confirm that this is just an abbreviation in your code to protect privacy?

Comment: @Dan - I can confirm that the "c:/.../"path was to protect privacy.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - Other scripts in that DIR work fine so I don't think that is the problem.

Also I tried removing the os.path.join() and just had it referencing the "PW" & "LW" variables. This also didn't work.

I will try the arcpy.AddMessage script suggested.

Comment: You'll need a lot of them, every blank line for a start, then when the error causing line is located you can find and replace arcpy.AddMessage(sys._getframe().f_lineno) with an empty string to get rid of them all at once or put a # in front just in case you need them again.

Comment: Always best to debug without `arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three errors in my script.

The first was the inclusion of os.path.join() - this is not required as I am not using a .gdb.

The corrected code for this section is below:

```
# Want to join Points to Lines and 'count' the number of joins for each pipe to junction
targetFeatures = PW
joinFeatures = LW

# Output will be the target features, (Points) with the 'count' of Lines joined.
outfc = O_PL
```

The second error was:
    L_IDFieldIndex = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("L_ID")
This field exists in my larger script but not in my 'test' script'

The third error is on the last line: "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE" - in order to keep a count I need to join one to one so the points aren't duplicated.